# Install4j migrate macOS installations from "folder installer" to "single bundle archive"

Tags: macos, install4j

We are switching from using the "folder installer" option to the "single bundle archive" option for our macOS distribution media. What is the best way to update the existing installed versions to the new single bundle archive format, while keeping it simple for the end user?

Is there a way to remove the current installation and install the new App automatically?

The new DMG does not contain an installer and the installation process is just to drag&drop the App into Applications.

Answer (score 1):

> The new DMG does not contain an installer and the installation process is just to drag&drop the App into Applications.

This makes it difficult to provide any automatic migration at installation time, because the user only copies a directory in the Finder. You can add a "Setup application" on the "Launcher" step of the media wizard that will be run when the users launchers the app for the first time.

[image]

In that custom installer application (which is configured under Installer->Screens & Actions) you can add logic for the migration from old installations that have been installed with a folder installer.

Comment: So the automatic update of the "old" application can not be used. The user would have to manually download the new .dmg and install the application, which would then be able to read properties from the previous installation for the initial setup and possibly remove the old installation.
I can see how macOS would complain about the application accessing /Applications to manage existing apps.

Maybe maintaining the current folder distribution just for updates and offering the new .dmg for new installations could be a good compromise?

Comment: Sure, that sound like a good idea that will minimize problems.

Comment: Is there a way to make the "Setup application" run the first time after every update?

Comment: `Is there a way to make the "Setup application" run the first time after every update?` That's how it works